# Scala how can I return an async string back

Tags: scala, asynchronous

I have a login form that attempts to login users with their email and password and it is done in an async way. I first check if the email or password fields are blank and if they are then I want to return it back. The thing is that I am new to scala and do not know how to return a string back in an asynchronous way. This is my code

```
  def login= Action.async {implicit request=>


      case class Login(password:String,email:String)

      val formm = Form(mapping(
        "email"->text,
        "password" -> text)(Login.apply)(Login.unapply))
      val getData= formm.bindFromRequest.get


    val email = getData.email
    var password = getData.password

    var idd = -1;
    if (email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {

      // How can I make this Ok() return back async
       Ok("Empty Fields");


      }



    else
  {

      val tryout =
        sql"""select id,password from profiles where email=$email and password=$password;""".as[(Int,String)]

      db.run(tryout).map { Result =>
        Ok(Result.toString())
      }
}
```

**My problem is with the Ok() in the If block how can I make it return back the Ok() asynchronously ?** The rest of the code works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply wrap it in a successful future:

```
Future.successful(Ok("Empty Fields"))
```